# Open a port in a debian machine

Tags: debian

I have a process in local (a server) that accepts socket connections in a port. Everything works well at localhost.

However from outside I recive connection refused. How can I open this port outside?

Comment: What do you mean "from outside". Outside of your own computer but within your own network (Home-network) or from outside your network (i.e. "The Internet")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First ensure that the port is listening in the appropriate interface:

```
# netstat -an | grep $port.*LISTEN
```

If you use `iptables`, open the port to accept connections.

You don't give details on whether it's an UDP or TCP port, so I can't provide an example.

Comment: TCP Connection. Im absolutelly newbie in this issues. :S

Comment: Im sorry, that was my fault. The port was really open. The problem was with my C project, that only accepted connections from localhost :(